# Get window titles not getting other window for Internet Explorer

Tags: python, internet-explorer, robotframework

I am currently working on a robotframework test on IE which a test needs to change to a new window. By using `Get Window Titles`, I only get 1 title which is the main window but I'm not getting the newly opened window. Anyone can help for a solution for this?

ROBOT FRAMEWORK SCRIPT:

```
Search For Customer Via Find Button
    [Arguments]   ${customerNameField}    ${customerName}
    Set Delay    .1
    Sleep         3
    @{Window Names}    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    20s    5s    Get Window Titles
    Select Window      @{Window Names}[1]
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: what's the output from get window titles?  I've similar tests and haven't noticed this problem before

Comment: I only got [Home Page]. I should have got [Home Page, Ask Us Page]. The code above works on firefox. Its just ie that sucks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a registry key `TabProcGrowth` with the value of `0` in the registry editor with the path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main`. This will make you see other windows.

NOTE: In my case, adding this made inputting text very very slow.